# Does all evolutionary algorithm encode the population in binary terms

Tags: algorithm, optimization, genetic-algorithm, heuristics, evolutionary-algorithm

I am new to heuristic methods of optimization and learning about different optimization algorithms available in this space like Gentic Algorithm, PSO, DE, CMA ES etc.. The general flow of any of these algorithms seem to be initialise a population, select, crossover and mutation for update , evaluate and the cycle continues. The initial step of population creation in genetic algorithm seems to be that each member of the population is encoded by a chromosome, which is a bitstring of 0s and 1s and then all the other operations are performed. GE has simple update methods to popualation like mutation and crossover, but update methods are different in other algorithms.

My query here is do all the other heuristic algorithms also initialize the population as bitstrings of 0 and 1s or do they use the general natural numbers?

Comment: Please expand the acronyms PSO, DE, CMA ES etc..

Comment: PSO - Particle Swarm optimization, DE- Differential Evolution

Comment: BRKGA uses floating-point numbers in [0, 1].

Comment: @DavidEisenstat does the floating point numbers get converted to bit stings for mutation and crossover in BRKGA ?

Comment: @cvg No, mutation and crossover operate directly on the floats. There's a problem-specific decoder that turns an array of floats into a solution.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat can you help me understand how is this decoder defined or elaborate a bit on the problem specific decoder that you are referring ?

Comment: It's a function from vectors to solutions. For example, if we were using BRKGA to solve the Traveling Salesman Problem (not a great idea; there are much better methods), we could define a genome as a map from graph nodes to [0, 1] and let the decoder sort the nodes by value. Another possible decoder would be to use this order as the order in which vertices are considered by a greedy insertion method. Lots of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

The representation of individuals in evolutionary algorithms (EA) depends on the representation of a candidate solution. If you are solving a combinatorial problem i.e. knapsack problem, the final solution is comprised of (0,1) string, so it makes sense to have a binary representation for the EA. However, if you are solving a continuous black-box optimisation problem, then it makes sense to have a representation with continuous decision variables.

In the old days, GA and other algorithms only used binary representation even for solving continuous problems. But nowadays, all the algorithms you mentioned have their own binary and continuous (and etc.) variants. For example, PSO is known as a continuous problem solver, but to update the individuals (particles), there are mapping strategies such as s-shape transform or v-shape transform to update the binary individuals for the next iteration.

My two cents: the choice of the algorithm relies on the type of the problem, and I personally won't recommend using a binary PSO at first try to solve a problem. Maybe there are benefits hidden there but need investigation.

Please feel free to extend your question.